# Inject dynamic script to each tab onLoad in Safari Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, google-chrome-extension, safari-extension

In Chrome there is a simple way to inject a dynamically loaded script into each tab onLoad, through the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` method, just like this:

```
$.get('somedomain.com/script.js', function(code) {
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tab_id, info, tab) {
            if (info['status'] == 'complete') {
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab_id, { file: 'jquery.js' });
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab_id, { code: code });
            }
        });
    });
```

Now, i tried porting same thing to Safari Extension, but i only found that i can supply the injected script in the extension builder, and the API description it too poor

Is there a way to do same in Safari?

ps: the script is loaded once in a background (so called 'global' in Safari) page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`addContentScript()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ExtensionClassRef/#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/SafariExtension/addContentScript) and [`addContentScriptFromURL()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ExtensionClassRef/#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/SafariExtension/addContentScriptFromURL).

Comment: yesss perfect! thanks :) so i just put in a "runAtEnd" boolean and it will run upon tab loading :) good